# How many bottles of beer on this wall?

Tags: ruby, class

Bellow is my first (and rather silly attempt) at creating a class for the ruby-kickstart course.

In my newbish mind this should work - but instead I get:

```
rubytest.rb:28:in `<main>': uninitialized constant BeerSong (NameError)
```

rb:28 is "def print_song"

```
Class BeerSong  
attr_accessor :beers

def initialize(beers)
 beers = 0  if beers < 0
 beers = 99 if beers > 99
 self.beers = beers
end


def print_song
        bottlecount = :beers

        letters_to_numbers = Hash.new 
        letters_to_numbers = {
                    "Ninety" => 90,
                    "Eighty" => 80,
                    "Seventy" => 70,
                    "Sixty" => 60,
                    "Fifty" => 50,
                    "Fourty" => 40,
                    "Thirty" => 30,
                    "Twenty" => 20,
                    "Nineteen" => 19,
                    "Eightteen" => 18,
                    "Seventeen" => 17,
                    "Sixteen" => 16,
                    "Fifteen" => 15,
                    "Fourteen" => 14,
                    "Thirteen" => 13,
                    "Twelve" => 12,
                    "Eleven" => 11,
                    "Ten" => 10,
                    "nine" => 9,
                    "eight" => 8,
                    "seven" => 7,
                    "six" => 6,
                    "five" => 5,
                    "four" => 4,
                    "three" => 3,
                    "two" => 2,
                    "one" => 1
        }

                    while bottlecount > 1
                            bottlecount_primerA = bottlecount.to_s
                            bottlecount_primerB = bottlecount_primerA[0].to_i*10
                            bottlecount_primerC = bottlecount_primerA[1].to_i

                                if bottlecount > 19 && bottlecount_primerC != 0
                                        bottlecount_tens = letters_to_numbers.key(bottlecount_primerB)
                                        bottlecount_singels = letters_to_numbers.key(bottlecount_primerC)
                                        bottlecount_text = "#{bottlecount_tens}-#{bottlecount_singels}"
                                    elsif bottlecount > 19 && bottlecount_primerC == 0
                                        bottlecount_tens = letters_to_numbers.key(bottlecount_primerB)
                                        bottlecount_text = "#{bottlecount_tens}"
                                    elsif bottlecount > 9 && bottlecount < 20 
                                        bottlecount_text = letters_to_numbers.key(bottlecount)
                                end

                            puts "#{bottlecount_text} bottles of beer on the wall,"
                            puts "#{bottlecount_text} bottles of beer,"
                            puts "Take one down, pass it around,"       
                            bottlecount -= 1
                    end
                    puts "one bottle of beer on the wall,"
                    puts "one bottle of beer,"
                    puts "Take one down, pass it around,"   
                    puts "zero bottles of beer on the wall"
end

Bottleman = BeerSong.new (99)

Bottleman.print_song
```

Been scratching my head for a while, but not sure why the class does not want to go.

Comment: In ruby, `class` is lower cased. You are also going to want to lowercase your variable `Bottleman`. It is the community standard in ruby to use 2 spaces for indentation instead of tabs. You also do not need to use `Hash.new`, just to replace the empty hash with your created hash (`letters_to_numbers = { ... }` creates a different hash for you).

Answer (score 3):

Not only is `class BeerSong` incorrectly typed as `Class BeerSong`, but the class is not properly terminated by an `end` statement. So Ruby tries to find the definition of `BeerSong` instead of understanding that you're trying to define it. Failing to find it, it returns the uninitialized constant error.

This is the kind of error that makes Rubyists religious about correct indentation, so that things like missing `end` statements are easy to see.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that makes programmers religious about indentation. You could get the same (type of) error in Java or C.

Comment: thanks for input :) when I did proper indentation I saw the problem (and converted to religion)